# <input type="number"/> with a custom step "n" but allow decimals

Tags: html, input, numbers, decimal

I would like to have an `<input type="number">` with a step without decimals, but keep allowing decimals input, so the field doesn't go in an invalid state

```
<input type="number" step="5.00000" />
```

Pressing <kbd>^</kbd> will increment of 5, but putting 5.5 in the field will result in a invalid state.

Better understanding here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89ydzs

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```html
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

Also, you can make your own number input using javascript.

```js
function inRangeOf(value, min, max) {
  if (min !== undefined) value = Math.max(min, value);
  if (max !== undefined) value = Math.min(max, value);
  return value;
}

function processValue(value, min, max) {
  var dots = value.match(/\./g);
  if (value.length > 1 && value[value.length - 1] == '.' && value[value.length - 2] != '-' && (!dots || dots.length < 2)) {
    return inRangeOf(parseFloat(value.substring(0, value.length-1)), min, max) + '.';
  } else {
    return inRangeOf(parseFloat(value), min, max);
  }
}

function processKey(evt, min, max) {
  if (evt.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    evt.target.value = inRangeOf((parseFloat(evt.target.value) || 0) + 1, min, max) + '';
    return true;
  } else if (evt.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    evt.target.value = inRangeOf((parseFloat(evt.target.value) || 0) - 1, min, max) + '';
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = processValue(this.value, 0, 100) || ''" onkeydown="return processKey(event, 0, 100)" />
```

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear. I want to customize the step as I want. I edited my question replacing 1 with 5, so any doesn't work

Comment: @YohanDahmani I think it's not possible. But you can make your own component using Js with step 1 that accepts any float.

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping I could use the HTML5 form validation because I'm using min, max as well with input.validity object ... thanks for trying

Comment: still doesn't quite fit my needs but yes I'll go with a custom component where i'll implement my own controls and hide html5 defaults, thanks